# Gerar Inserts a partir de uma tabela já populada

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho uma  tabela populada e preciso gerar os `scripts` de `insert` dos dados armazenados nela, não posso exportar, tem que ser o `script` de `insert into ...` 
 Fazer pelo `select` concatenando é muito trabalhoso, já que tenho que fazer isso em mais de uma tabela e todas elas possuem muitos campos. Gostaria de saber se existe uma `procedure`/programa que gere os `inserts` dos dados dessa tabela.

Utilizamos `SqlServer - 2016`

Comment: Você poderia fornecer mais detalhes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível também pelo Managment Studio (SSMS)...

1. Botão Direito na sua Base e Vá em Tasks -> Generate Scripts

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Especifique as tabelas que deseja exportar. Feito isso, clique em Next.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Em Set Script Options, clique no botão Advanced.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Altere o parametro Types of data to script para Data Only. Isso definirá que seja exportados os inserts com os dados de sua tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. Finalize e veja o resultado...

Comment: Muito obrigado @julio, era exatamente o que eu queria.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a `procedure` abaixo:

```
if object_id('ferramenta.gerar_insercao', 'P') is null
begin
  exec('create procedure ferramenta.gerar_insercao as');
end;
go

alter procedure ferramenta.gerar_insercao(@schema    varchar(200) = 'dbo',
                                          @tabela    varchar(200),
                                          @where     varchar(max) = null,
                                          @top       int = null,
                                          @insert    varchar(max) output)
as
begin
  declare @insert_campos varchar(max),
          @select        varchar(max),
          @erro          varchar(500),
          @query         varchar(max);

  declare @valores table(descricao varchar(max));

  set nocount on;

  -- Pega a relação de colunas
  select @insert_campos = isnull(@insert_campos + ', ', '') + c.name,
         @select = case type_name(c.system_type_id)
                      when 'varchar' then isnull(@select + ' + '', '' + ', '') + ' isnull('''''''' + cast(' + c.name + ' as varchar) + '''''''', ''null'')'
                      when 'datetime' then isnull(@select + ' + '', '' + ', '') + ' isnull('''''''' + convert(varchar, ' + c.name + ', 121) + '''''''', ''null'')'
                      else isnull(@select + ' + '', '' + ', '') + 'isnull(cast(' + c.name + ' as varchar), ''null'')'
                    end
    from sys.columns c with(nolock)
         inner join sys.tables t with(nolock) on t.object_id = c.object_id
         inner join sys.schemas s with(nolock) on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
   where s.name = @schema
     and t.name = @tabela;

  -- Caso não tenha encontrado as colunas...
  if @insert_campos is null or @select is null
  begin
    set @erro = 'Tabela ' + @schema + '.' + @tabela + ' não existe na base de dados.';
    raiserror(@erro, 16, 1);
    return;
  end;

  set @insert_campos = 'insert into ' + @schema + '.' + @tabela + '(' + @insert_campos + ')';

  if isnull(@where, '') <> '' and charindex('where', ltrim(rtrim(@where))) < 1
  begin
    set @where = 'where ' + @where;
  end
  else
  begin
    set @where = '';
  end;

  set @query = 'select ' + isnull('top(' + cast(@top as varchar) + ')', '') + @select + ' from ' + @schema + '.' + @tabela + ' with (nolock) ' + @where;

  insert into @valores(descricao)
  exec(@query);

  set @insert = isnull(@insert + char(10), '') + '--' + upper(@schema + '.' + @tabela);

  select @insert = @insert + char(10) + @insert_campos + char(10) + 'values(' + v.descricao + ');' + char(10) + 'go' + char(10)
    from @valores v
   where isnull(v.descricao, '') <> '';
end;
go
```

Da seguinte forma:

```
declare @insert varchar(max),
        @parte  varchar(max),
        @inicio int,
        @final  int;

set @inicio = 1;

exec ferramenta.gerar_insercao @schema = 'dbo',
                               @tabela = 'cliente',
                               @where  = 'codigo = 1',
                               @insert = @insert output;

-- Dá um comando "print" a cada quebra de linha para não estourar o tamanho máximo de 8000
while len(@insert) > 0
begin
  set @final = charindex(char(10), @insert);

  if @final = 0
  begin
    set @final = len(@insert) + 1;
  end;

  print substring(@insert, @inicio, @final - 1);
  set @insert = substring(@insert, @final + 1, len(@insert) - @final + 1);
end;
```

O resultado seria algo assim:

```
--DBO.CLIENTE
insert into dbo.cliente(codigo, nome, tipo)
values(1, 'NOME DO CLIENTE', 'F');
go
```

Caso não queria utilizar o `where`, você pode usar o parâmetro `@top`:

```
declare @insert varchar(max),
        @parte  varchar(max),
        @inicio int,
        @final  int;

set @inicio = 1;

exec ferramenta.gerar_insercao @schema = 'dbo',
                               @tabela = 'cliente',
                               @top    = 100,
                               @insert = @insert output;

-- Dá um comando "print" a cada quebra de linha para não estourar o tamanho máximo de 8000
while len(@insert) > 0
begin
  set @final = charindex(char(10), @insert);

  if @final = 0
  begin
    set @final = len(@insert) + 1;
  end;

  print substring(@insert, @inicio, @final - 1);
  set @insert = substring(@insert, @final + 1, len(@insert) - @final + 1);
end;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sorack, Porém encontrei esta ferramenta [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org), onde eu consigo exportar os dados na forma de insert's.

Comment: @EmersonRodrigues ué, por que tirou a confirmação de resposta? A resposta não te atendeu?

Comment: atendeu, porém a resposta do julio me atendeu melhor. Tentei deixar as duas como certas, mas acho que não dá (sou noob no stack). Agradeço pela boa vontade.